# Shorten link text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Its probably really simple but I cant figure out how I would do this
I want to shorten a link if its longer than 30 characters add ... at the end and make it possible to see the full link on hover like on amazon.

[image]

My function that doesnt work

```
function shortenLink() {
    var string = $("div a").text();

    if (string.length > 30) {
        string.substring(0, 30);
        string.append('...')
    }
}
```

Comment: assign that string back to anchor tag like $("div a").text(string)

Comment: you can do this with only  CSS ... https://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Comment: You're assuming that all string methods alter the original string. They don't.

Comment: For this kind of question you should also provide your [mcve] HTML, because there are - almost certainly - CSS-only options for this that don't require JavaScript.

Comment: @DavidThomas I don't think that's possible in this case with a 30 letter character limit prerequisite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this using jquery:

```
$("div a").each(function(i,v){
    $(v).attr('title',$(v).text());
    if($(v).text().length > 30){
        var str = $(v).text().substring(0,30) + "...";
        $(v).text(str);
    }
});
```

Comment: @Madmin you should mark this answer as the solution if it solved it for you.

Comment: yeah I wanted to but I had to wait longer before I could accept it

Answer (score 0):

Use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` for ...

and  `-webkit-line-clamp: 3;` as per your lines requirements.

Hope this helps :)

For example..

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #eaeaea;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  font-family:arial;
}
.demo {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="demo">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ut odio temporibus voluptas error distinctio hic quae corrupti vero doloribus optio! Inventore ex quaerat modi blanditiis soluta maiores illum, ab velit.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you account for the 30 letter character limit specified by the OP with this method?

Comment: also use link instead of p and add title attribute

Answer (score 0):

substring returns a new string- thus it does not change your current string.
Thus in any solution you would want to reassign the text to the element.

( using $(elementQuery).text(newValue) )

a simpler solution

```js
function shortenString(string,maxLength=30){
  return string.length >= maxLength? string.slice(0,maxLength-3) + '...' : string
}

// You can get this string using the $(<EL>).text() function.
console.log(shortenString('ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss'))
console.log(shortenString('ss'))
```